# How do we remove the ugly link in a sendgrid email?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, smtp, sendgrid

So we have a link to our site at the footer section of our emails, however, sendgrid seems to be turning this basic link into a really ugly looking link as seen below:

[image]

How do we just show the regular URL and not have this big link?

Please help! There doesn't seem to be any documentation about this.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to Sendgrid's [click tracking](https://sendgrid.com/docs/User_Guide/Settings/tracking.html). If you turn off click tracking, it should preserve the original link.